# TS2322: Type 'string | 3000' is not assignable to number

Tags: typescript

This small line throws an error (`TS2322: Type 'string | 3000' is not assignable to number`) because `process.env.PORT` is of type `string`

```
const port: number = process.env.PORT || 3000;
```

This also returns an error because `process.env.PORT` may be `undefined`

```
const port: number = +process.env.PORT || 3000;
```

Is there a concise way of writing this without getting a type error?

ie. if `process.env.PORT` is set then convert that `string` to a `number` otherwise return a constant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `+` to ensure the `string || 3000` expression is a `number`:

```
const port: number = +(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a ternary operator

```
const port: number = process.env.PORT ? +process.env.PORT : 3000;
```